# Improve Script performance by caching Spreadsheet values

Tags: caching, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to develop a webapp using Google Apps Script to be embedded into a Google Site which simply displays the contents of a Google Sheet and filters it using some simple parameters. For the time being, at least. I may add more features later.

I got a functional app, but found that filtering could often take a while as the client sometimes had to wait up to 5 seconds for a response from the server. I decided that this was most likely due to the fact that I was loading the spreadsheet by ID using the SpreadsheetApp class every time it was called.

I decided to cache the spreadsheet values in my `doGet` function using the CacheService and retrieve the data from the cache each time instead.

However, for some reason this has meant that what was a 2-dimensional array is now treated as a 1-dimensional array. And, so, when displaying the data in an HTML table, I end up with a single column, with each cell being occupied by a single character.

This is how I have implemented the caching; as far as I can tell from the API reference I am not doing anything wrong:

```
function doGet() {
  CacheService.getScriptCache().put('data', SpreadsheetApp
                                  .openById('####')
                                  .getActiveSheet()
                                  .getDataRange()
                                  .getValues());

  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function getData() {
  return CacheService.getScriptCache().get('data');
}
```

This is my first time developing a proper application using GAS (I have used it in Sheets before). Is there something very obvious I am missing? I didn't see any type restrictions on the CacheService reference page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CacheService stores Strings, so objects such as your two-dimensional array will be coerced to Strings, which may not meet your needs.

Use the JSON utility to take control of the results.

```
myCache.put( 'tag', JSON.stringify( myObj ) );

...

var cachedObj = JSON.parse( myCache.get( 'tag' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! This has made queries a lot faster. However, it is now taking longer on the initial load of the page (8 sec). Any tips on how to get that down or will that just have to be an acceptable trade-off?

Comment: Apparently, loading lots of data in templates is bad. This is my problem. I will change to asynchronous loading (which is the recommended practice) and see if things improve.

Comment: Yes, asynch loading will shorten the initial load. The new "IFRAME" sandbox type should also help, but beware that it's currently [broken in IE](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4611).

Comment: Thanks. This is a very limited use application, though, and I do not believe anyone who is going to be using it will be running IE. Handy to know, though!

Answer (score 2):

Cache expires.  The `put` method, *without* an **expirationInSeconds** parameter expires in 10 minutes.  If you need your data to stay alive for more than 10 minutes, you need to specify an **expirationInSeconds**, and the maximum is 6 hours.  So, if you specifically do NOT need the data to expire, **Cache** might not be the best use.

You can use Cache for something like controlling how long a user can be logged in.

You could also try using a global variable, which some people would tell you to never use.  To declare a global variable, define the variable outside of any function.

Comment: I tried using a global variable but it didn't seem to persist. I set it in the `doGet()` function but it was said to be `null` when accessed later through a Client API call.

I have written the app such that it will refresh the cache if it has expired. Is this bad practice?

Comment: You need to declare the global outside of the `doGet()`.  Currently I don't have any experience refreshing the cache.  Bad practice?  Whatever works best for me is what I do.